# WCF with tcp.net binding testing with JMeter

Tags: wcf, testing, wcf-binding, jmeter, nettcpbinding

I have a problem that in JMeter I can setup server / port, but my application is hosting on IIS 7.5 and WCF service is a "Application" under specific web site. So the service endpoint is

http://localhost:8002/Some.Aplication/Some.Application.svc

WCF application is supporting tcp.net binding also and I should use it(tcp.net).

Ho can I set up JMeter for sending specific packet over tcp to this endpoint ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler), and probably write a custom TCPClient class for it for easier handling of custom reads/writes.